# mirroring iPad screen to VGA

Tags: objective-c, ipad, mirroring, vga

I tried mirroring the screen of a simple new TabBarApplication with iphoneos-screen-mirroring for iPad:

http://code.google.com/p/iphoneos-screen-mirroring/

Everytime (also without including the code) if I try to activate the TV-out in Simulator mode the app crashes without errors.

If the external TV-out is activated it staies black (code includet).

appDelegate:

```
#import "iPadVGAAppDelegate.h"
#import "UIApplication+ScreenMirroring.h"


@implementation iPadVGAAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize tabBarController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setupScreenMirroringWithFramesPerSecond:20.0];

    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same behaviour.  I think the technique it uses means you have to test on a real device.  The same code on a real device (iPad) for me worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/123

[Rob Terrell's TVOutManager](https://github.com/robterrell/TVOutManager) is the solution.

The next line is all your need:  `[[TVOutManager sharedInstance] startTVOut];`